# Suggestion for a way to design a document changes, versioning and merging database

Tags: database-design, merge, nosql, rdbms, document-oriented-db

I'm tasked to develop a web application that track document changes, versions and merges. The following are the details involved:

1. Agency / Organization details
2. Legislation details
3. Document details (contains agencies & legislation details)

Requirements:

1. A document can be removed, simplified, amended, deleted and merged with any documents. Same goes for agencies and legislations.
2. Changes happen when the document is undergoing review process or the agencies / legislations removed, changed or merged.
3. All these changes must be tracked and user must be able to view historical changes to all of the items above.

My initial idea is to use adjacency list with versions for each document, agency and legislation but I want to explore other ways of tackling this problem.

I welcome all RDBMS or Non-RDBMS / NoSQL solutions or suggestions.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using a version control tool rather than trying to build your own thing.  Can you use git or subversion?  What format are the documents?